# Passing wrong model item to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use two tables in the same View in my `asp.net mvc` project but I'am doing some errors and I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Question]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[projet.Models.userdbcontext]`

Class `Questions.cs`:

```
public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int userID { get; set; }
            
    }
```

Class `User.cs`:

```
public class User
    {
        

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Model `userdbcontext.cs`:

```
{
        public userdbcontext()
        { }
        public DbSet<Question> Questiondb { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Usersdb { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the controller:

```
 private userdbcontext db = new userdbcontext();
        // GET: question
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var l = from e in db.Questiondb
                    select e;
            return View(l);
        }
```

The view:

```
@model IEnumerable<projet.Models.userdbcontext>
```

Comment: I know that I have to pass both tables to the view but I don't know how

Comment: I tried something like: `var l = from e in db.Questiondb from ee in db.UsersDb where e.Id != null && ee.Id != null select new userdbcontext { Questiondb =e , UsersDb =ee}   return View(l);` but I got : `cannot implicitly convert type 'projet.Models.Question' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<projet.Models.Questions>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error is that you are trying to send a `DbSet<>` to the view which is hard to manipulate so to solve the problem, you have to create a new class `ViewModel` in which you store the value of the `DbSet<>` as `List<>` then you pass it to the View like this :

Model userdbcontext.cs:

```
public class userdbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public userdbcontext()
        { }
        public DbSet<Question> Questiondb { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Usersdb { get; set; }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Question> Question { get; set; }
        public List<User> User { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller:

```
private userdbcontext db = new userdbcontext();
        // GET: question
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var l = new ViewModel();
            l.Question = db.Questiondb.ToList();
            l.User = db.Usersdb.ToList();
            
            return View(l);
        }
```

and in the view:

```
@model projet.Models.ViewModel
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create  a view model:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
   public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var vm = new ViewModel{
      Questions = db.Questiondb.ToList(),
      Users= db.Userdb.ToList()
   }

   return View(vm);
}
```

view

```
@model projet.Models.ViewModel

....
<!-- Accessing Model Variables -->
@Model.Questions...
@Model.Users...
```